# "You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders." error ( React, Typescript )

Tags: reactjs, typescript, npm, webpack, mocha.js

So I have package 1 that I wrote in Typescript that contains mocha tests and I'm pretty sure that it works as it should. I push all the code to the git provider and pull it via npm on package 2. When I start React with Typescript on package 2, I get the following:[image]

I tried adding `webpack.config.js`, various `tsconfig.json` configuration changes and multiple `npm` commands that are connected to cache cleaning and reinstalling but nothing works. This error is just plain weird because, from what I know, there shouldn't be any compilation errors regarding class variables.

Comment: Try deleting the node_modules and package-lock.json and reinstall the packages.

Comment: As mentioned in the post, I already tried that multiple different times together with reinstalling the whole project. It just doesn't want to go past this compilation error.

Comment: Ok, can we see your webpack.config.js file contents?

Comment: I do not have the webpack.config.js since this project is built with CRA. I think I need to compile the package 1 before installing it, I will try now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**FIX**

This was a very quick fix. So, in short, if the provider with which you started your Typescript application doesn't provide you with webpack or babel file you will have to transpile any module from node_modules into Javascript that you try to import. In this case I just transpiled package 1 and package 2 worked perfectly.